# Aligning Column Header of datagrid with grouped buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

My requirement is to group datagrid rows based on a condition and display the grouped rows in alternating colours along with an edit button for each group. The problem here is my datagrid Column headers are not aligning with the Data grid data rows .
[Current Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlB1x.png)

I have already gone through a lot of posts with not much help I have tried this post as well [WPF DataGrid GroupStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686170/wpf-datagrid-group-style) . This example has group style for a grid but I tried to do the same for a datagrid.

Current XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="TimeSeriesDataGrid.View.TimeSeriesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
             xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:TimeSeriesDataGrid.ViewModel"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:TimeSeriesDataGrid.Converters"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
             xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" Title="{Binding WindowTitle}" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:TimeSeriesViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEFFF" Offset="0.836"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Window.Resources>
        <converter:RowColorConverter x:Key="RowColorConverter" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TimeSeriesCollectionViewSource"  CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView" Source="{Binding GetTimeSeries}" >
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DocumentId"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
          </CollectionViewSource>
   </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid  
            DataContext="{StaticResource TimeSeriesCollectionViewSource}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedTimeSeries}"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            x:Name="dg_TimeSeriesEdit" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" 
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" 
            HeadersVisibility="Column" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
            MaxHeight="800" 
            MaxWidth="2550" 
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFC92222" 
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFC92222" 
            Width="Auto" 
            Height="Auto" >
              <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle AlternationCount="2" >
                     <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  Background="Transparent">
                                                <Button Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" Content="Edit" Margin="0,0,0,5" Height="Auto" Width="50" >
                                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                                            <local:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.EditGroupCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Items}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                </Button>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </StackPanel>             

                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
           <DataGrid.RowStyle>           
            <Style>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" 
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupItem}, 
                        Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), Converter={StaticResource RowColorConverter}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                .
                .
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Michal Ciechan Your answer helped me for a normal grid  solution and i tried to do the same for datagrid but couldnt make it work ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686170/wpf-datagrid-group-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to allign the header with data after TranslateTransform on datagridcolumn header

```
 <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TranslateTransform X="50"></TranslateTransform>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
```